# Extract a 8 digit number from string of variable size

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a string of undetermined size which contains a 8 digit number. Example:

```
This is 123456 a string
This is a new string 123456
123456 This is another string
```

How can I extract the integer value of such number?

Answer (score 2):

`NSString` has an instance method `-integerValue` which returns the integer value extracted from the string's contents. So `[@"123456" integerValue]` will return `123456`.

Comment: Hey Kevin thank                                                    But what If you did not know the  the interger  Value.. ALL you know is that < In this  full string> there is a an 8 digit interger number you need to pull   how could i do this???   im trying to get an interger value from a URL

Comment: @BriAnC: Your question is fairly unclear. What exactly are you trying to get? Just the first substring consisting of one or more digits?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is an NSScanner. Have the scanner scan up to the first occurrence of the  `decimalDigitCharacterSet` and then use `scanInteger:` to get the NSInteger value it finds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to pull numbers of any given format out of a string. If you just wanted to grab one integer from any given string (in this case, the first integer):

```
NSString* str = @"This is 123456 a string";

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@".*?(\\d+).*?" options:NULL error:nil];

NSArray* results = [regex matchesInString:str options:NULL range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];

NSString* str2 = [str substringWithRange:[(NSTextCheckingResult*)[results objectAtIndex:0] rangeAtIndex:1]];

NSLog(@"%@",str2);

NSInteger intResult = [str2 integerValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract a number of the given digits from a string of undeterminate length.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSNumber* numberFromStringWithDigits(NSString* string, NSUInteger digits)
{
      NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];  
      NSCharacterSet *allowed = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];  
      while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {  
          NSString *buffer;  
          if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:allowed intoString:&buffer]) {  
              if ([buffer length]==digits){
                  return [NSNumber numberWithInt:[buffer integerValue]];
              }
          } else {        
              [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];  
          } 
      }
      return nil;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *url = @"http://garb23age.com/x555xx/xx12345678xxxxxx";
        NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];  

        NSNumber *n = numberFromStringWithDigits(url,8);

        NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];  
        NSLog(@"%@ in %f seconds",n,-elapsedTime); // 12345678 in 0.000188 seconds
    }
}
```

@Bri An C: probably what you want is to extract the `parameterString` of the `NSURL`. Maybe you should post the URL to ask for alternate solutions.